# Memory Mapped Region initial data

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management

I want to create memory-mapped region using `CreateFileMapping` without any specific disk-file bound, but bound (using `MapViewOfFileEx`) to a specific memory address. Protection of such region needs to be read-only from beginning. Then, I cannot write data to such a region. If this region would be created for specific disk-file, initial data would come from file content. How I can fill this read-only region with initial data?

Example:
Most Windows processes have memory regions which are mapped (and not bound to any file path) and read-only since creation, they contain data. How was this achieved? How were these regions filled with data?

Comment: *"bound(using MapViewOfFileEx) to specific process memory address"* It's not clear what you mean by that. You can only map shared memory into your own process, not some other process. Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What's your actual goal with all this?

Comment: edited for more clear

Comment: What makes you believe that *"most windows processes have memory regions which are mapped(and not bound to any file path) and read only since creation"*? What's your evidence for this claim?

Comment: I seen this using debugger, some memory regions are mapped to some file path, some do not contain file path. But the question is not about evidences, it's about how to make such region.

Comment: they first map section with readwrite protection, and then map with readonly

Comment: Why does it need to be readonly from the beginning? If it's named and you wish to restrict access from other processes, set the security descriptor to only allow query and map-read access (`SECTION_QUERY | SECTION_MAP_READ`).

Answer (score 2):

exist only one way do this - first map section with `PAGE_READWRITE`, init it content, possible unmap, and then map it again - with `PAGE_READONLY` protection. for example

```
ULONG demo_map(PVOID BaseAddress, ULONG size, ULONG (*Init)(PVOID pv, ULONG size))
{
    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;
    if (HANDLE hSection = CreateFileMappingW(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size, 0))
    {
        if (PVOID pv = MapViewOfFile(hSection, FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            dwError = Init(pv, size);
            UnmapViewOfFile(pv);
        }
        else
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
        }

        if (!dwError)
        {
            dwError = MapViewOfFileEx(hSection, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0, BaseAddress) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
        }

        CloseHandle(hSection);
    }

    return dwError;
}
```